# Manipulating Duplicates

Tags: r

I have a vector in R, with some duplicates:

```
v <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3)
```

Now I want a function that replaces the duplicates to get a sequence of increasing suffixes:

```
result <- c(1,1.2,1.3,2,2.2,3)
```

Comment: The suffixes start at `0.2` and increase by `0.1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ave`, you can create a sequence number for each repeat :

```
ave(v, v, FUN = seq_along)
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 1
```

Divide this by 10 to get

```
ave(v, v, FUN = seq_along)/10
#[1] 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.1 0.2 0.1
```

Now add `v` to it

```
v1 <- v + ave(v, v, FUN = seq_along)/10
v1
#[1] 1.1 1.2 1.3 2.1 2.2 3.1
```

Now, since you don't want to change the first value of each group you can do :

```
v1[!duplicated(v)] <- unique(v)
v1
#[1] 1.0 1.2 1.3 2.0 2.2 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `ave`. Though [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63265703/8245406) already posted a solution also with `ave`, I believe this one is different.

```
ave(v, v, FUN = function(x) x + c(0, seq_along(x)[-1])/10)
#[1] 1.0 1.2 1.3 2.0 2.2 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using `dplyr`, maybe not so easy as the previous answers of @RuiBarradas and @RonakShah because you have to transform into dataframe and make some manipulations but it can be helpful:

```
library(tidyverse)
v <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3)
#Dataframe
v1 <- data.frame(v)
#Mutate
v1 %>% group_by(v) %>% mutate(v2=as.character(1:n()),
                              v2=ifelse(v2=='1',as.character(v),paste0(v,'.',v2))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% select(v2)

# A tibble: 6 x 1
  v2   
  <chr>
1 1    
2 1.2  
3 1.3  
4 2    
5 2.2  
6 3
```